# Whats a more efficient way to write this python code? (7 nested loops code takes too long time)

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
letters_list = list(letters)

plates = []
for letter_1 in letters_list:
for letter_2 in letters_list:
    for letter_3 in letters_list:
        for num_1 in range(1, 10):
            for num_2 in range(10):
                for num_3 in range(10):
                    for num_4 in range(10):
                        plate = [num_1, letter_1, letter_2, letter_3, num_2, num_3, num_4]
                        plates.append(plate)

print(len(plates))
```

Currently this code is running for 10+ mins.

1. I've heard python lists are not the fastests but is it normal for this code to run this long or something is wrong with my laptop?
2. Whats a more efficient way to write this python code?

Comment: What is the expected output? If you want all combinations of letters, then use `itertools` module

Comment: If you simply want the length, then that's just the multiplication of each loop range, and you dont need loops at all

Comment: Okay, so whats `plates` for? You couldve reached the same answer with adding up a number

Comment: What even are you doing??

Comment: If you really need to create the `plates` list it'll be probably more efficient to work with the `array` module because their elements are all of the same type, so Python does not have to check the type for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same output as the final print statement shown, you can multiply the range of the lists together

```
>>> import string
>>> print(len(string.ascii_lowercase)**3 * 10**3 * 9)
158184000
```

If you actually needed the `plates` list of that many elements, there isn't really a much better way to generate it.